# Is there a way to make the tabs in tab pane more thick in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, tabs, width, pane

Im using netbeans 7.4.
Im going to create a JFrame using nebeans forms which contain a tab pane.
I have set the tab placement property to "left" and I have added a few tabs.
But the tabs are so thin. i need to increase the area of a tab(not the JPanel inside the tab pane but the tabs (which contain the titles of tabs)).
Can someone please explain me how can i change tabs' appearance and the area(height or thicknes)?

this is like what i need
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAo4f.jpg

Comment: what i need is something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/lAo4f.jpg

Comment: Like I said, please add your code/any attempts. Members of this website are not here to do your work, they are here to HELP you do your work.

Comment: Ylun im sorry but there is nothing much to add as the coding I m just using netbeans forms, there i did not do much more than adding a tabpan and adding some JPanels to it... so all the codings are auto generated.